# Run dotnet test without full SDK installed

Tags: .net, .net-core, nunit, nunit-console, dotnet-test

I would like to run some nUnit tests on a build server, without having to install the .NET Core SDK there.

The tests target `netcoreapp3.1`.

For .NET Framework it was possible to run them using the [`nunit-console-runner`](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console), but it doesn't seem to be possible for .NET Core - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52854848/532575.

If found this issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1224, but it doesn't seem to offer any reasonable solution.

Similar question: [Run xUnit tests without SDK installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57897167/532575)

Comment: It is designed to be part of .NET Core SDK, so you must have the dependency installed.

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution by any chance?

Comment: @JPGarza no, unfortunately not. :(